# Calling non static method from static method USING instance created in the static method

Tags: c#, multithreading, static, non-static

i try to write my own Console Snake game, the problem is this..
I have my whole game in main thread, then I created addVlakno (new thread) to count seconds there, so it can every second call an method from instance of hra created in Main, so it will Clear console and do some methods to be moved.

```
class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Hra hra = new Hra();
            Thread addVlakno = new Thread(Run);
            addVlakno.Start();

...

        }

        public static void Run()
        {

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            hra.method(); // The problem is here* 

        }
    }
```

*I know i have to have an existing instance of Hra here, but i need to use the instance created in Main, is is possible? By some delegates, or some pointers or ather way? Because the created hra has all the values for the game, i need to use them.

I tried to put `Hra hra = new Hra();` before Main, but in this case, i couldn't use it even in the main.

Comment: "but in this case, i couldnt use it even in the main." be a bit more specific about this - what exactly happened (and how did the code look)?

Comment: How about `static Hra hra = new Hra();` before `Main`?

Comment: You can't use `hra` inside `Run()` because as it stands now `hra` is a _local variable_ in `Main`. If you want to access this inside `Run()` you should declare `hra` as an `static` variable in your `Program` class (`static Hra hra;` outside the `Main` method). That's not necessarily a good practice depending on what you are trying to do, but it will do for that test/practicing program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arguments as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Hra hra = new Hra();
    Thread addVlakno = new Thread(()=>Run(hra));
    addVlakno.Start();
}

public static void Run(Hra hra)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    hra.method(); // No problem here* 
}
```

Comment: @Ators : If this answer solved your problem mark it as accepted by pressing the check mark on its left.

Answer (score 2):

You currently can't access `hra` because a static method can only access other static variables and methods. You can declare `hra` as `static` outside `Main`:

```
static Hra hra = new Hra();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
...
}
```

This will allow you to access `hra` in `Run`.